# How to properly deploy an ASP.NET web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, model-view-controller, deployment, azure-web-app-service

So I have deployed a project of mine on Azure but when I load the page(https://sportarete.azurewebsites.net/) all I see is a blank gray screen. What could be the reason?

I had some warnings in the console log which I have resolved but still it's a gray screen.
Here is the console log:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7121
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5121
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: D:\Developer\Github Repos\SportArete\SportArete\
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.9 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.9' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (164ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Model], [t].[Price], [t].[ImageData], [c].[Name] AS [Category], [b].[Name] AS [Brand]
      FROM (
          SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [p].[Id], [p].[BrandId], [p].[CategoryId], [p].[ImageData], [p].[Model], [p].[Price], [p].[ViewsCount]
          FROM [Products] AS [p]
          WHERE [p].[IsAvailable] = CAST(1 AS bit)
          ORDER BY [p].[ViewsCount] DESC
      ) AS [t]
      INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [c] ON [t].[CategoryId] = [c].[Id]
      INNER JOIN [Brands] AS [b] ON [t].[BrandId] = [b].[Id]
      ORDER BY [t].[ViewsCount] DESC
```

Comment: Given you've provided practically no information, I could answer this with "because your site is actually a gray screen".

Comment: What do your logs say?

Answer (score 1):

The page returns an Error 500 Internal Server Error. As exact description for this error might contain sensible informations, the release build of ASP.NET does not show the error page that you might be familiar with while developing. See the console output of your application for more information.

PS: To see the error 500 use the DevTools of your browser, select the network tab and refresh the page.

[image: 500 Internal Error]

Comment: Oh right! Okay I will check it up now.